# Providing command line arguments in code blocks file(not a project)

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, codeblocks

I have seen question regarding the issue of taking comand line arguments in code blocks environment but the problem is that when I try to do Project-> Set program arguments in a file (not project based) then nothing happens my question is how can we provide command line arguments in a file which is not associated with any project or is there no way to do it? Also I am just a beginner so please explain if my question is stupid.

Comment: Probably there is no way. Unless starting the .exe manually via command line (or somehow else) counts.

Comment: Code::Blocks, like all modern C++ IDEs, is resolutely project-based. If you don't use a project, you lose most of the features of the IDE.